# Seaborn FacetGrid Plot with Multiple Y-Axis Ranges

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

How do i change the single y axis interval for every plot for Seaborn's FacetGrid Plot? If I plot a facetGrid that contains a lot of variable y values, Seaborn uses the default min and max y values of all the data to construct the only y-axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = sb.load_dataset('tips')
g = sb.FacetGrid(df, col = "time")
g.map(plt.hist, "tip")
plt.show()
```

Id like to see an axis for every plot, however it is not shown below on the second plot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass `sharey=False` to `sb.FacetGrid`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = sb.load_dataset('tips')
g = sb.FacetGrid(df, col = "time", sharey=False)
g.map(plt.hist, "tip")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that g.map() cannot use named parameters. Do NOT used x="tip". Use "tip" (with out parameter assignment) exactly as it is described in the answer.